# How can I get selected option contain object from single select - angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have array of object as follows:

```
var GlobalArray = [{'id':1,'Name':"ABC"},{'id':2,'Name':"XYZ"}]
```

And I want to get object values on selection of dropdown, but I didn't get it.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="docvalue" (change)="modify($event.target.value)" >
    <option *ngFor="let fop of GlobalArray " [value]="fop" selected]="fop.Name.IsSelected" >
      <h6>{{fop.Name}}</h6>
    </option>
</select>
```

(But in the function I get `[object object]`)

```
modify(obj){console.log("obj")
}
```

Comment: instead of `[value]="fop"` use `[ngValue]="fop"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component:

```
GlobalArray = [{'id':1,'Name':"ABC"},{'id':2,'Name':"XYZ"}];

// Choose whatever you want as the selected option on page load. 
// Set null if none to be selected.
docvalue = this.GlobalArray.find(x => x.id == 1); 

modify(){
  console.log(this.docvalue);
}
```

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="docvalue" (change)="modify()" >
    <option  *ngFor="let fop of GlobalArray " [ngValue]="fop">
      <h6>{{fop.Name}}</h6>
    </option>
</select>
```

Since you're using two way binding, you can simply use `this.docvalue` to get the selected value.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2mmfjw)

Answer (score 1):

Bind `fop.id` in the value, and if you want the selected object, just use `.find()`

Try like this:

.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="docvalue" (ngModelChange)="modify($event)" >
    <option *ngFor="let fop of GlobalArray " [value]="fop.id" [selected]="fop.Name.IsSelected" >
      <h6>{{fop.Name}}</h6>
    </option>
</select>
```

.ts

```
modify(id) {
   console.log(id);
   let obj = this.GlobalArray.find(x => x.id == id);
   console.log(obj);
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ahyet?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

Use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]` and pass `docvalue` to `modify(docvalue) function`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="docvalue"  (change)="modify(docvalue)">
    <option *ngFor="let fop of GlobalArray "  [ngValue]="fop" [selected]="fop.Name.IsSelected" >
      {{fop.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7khq4u)

Answer (score 0):

please use like below

```
<option *ngFor="let fop of GlobalArray " [ngValue]="fop.Name" [selected]="fop.Name.Name === 'ABC">
```

It will select the 
{'id':1,'Name':"ABC"} option from array
hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `$event` on `ngModelChange` and use `[value]="fop.Name"`

Try this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="docvalue" (ngModelChange)="modify($event)" >
    <option *ngFor="let fop of GlobalArray " [value]="fop.Name" [selected]="fop.Name.IsSelected" >
      <h6>{{fop.Name}}</h6>
    </option>
</select>
```

Here is the working **[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-ejt3gw?file=app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use `(ngModelChange)="modify($event)"` instead of `(change)="modify($event.target.value)"` and change `[value]="fop"` to `[value]="fop.Name"`

```
<select [(ngModel)]="docvalue" (ngModelChange)="modify($event)" >
        <option *ngFor="let fop of GlobalArray " [value]="fop.Name" >
          <h6>{{fop.Name}}</h6>
        </option>
</select>
```